# php conditional isn't working

Tags: php

I have a strange problem. My conditional isn't working:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?    address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=true');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

if($result !== null) {
    $result = @json_decode($result, true);
    $result = @$result['results'][0]['address_components'];

    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        if($value['types'][0] == 'administrative_area_level_2')
            return $value['long_name'];
    }
} else {
    throw new Exception('unable to look up the county');
}
```

I tried

```
if($result)
if($result != null)
if($result != '')
if(!empty($result))
if(isset($result))
```

neither one worked, script always goes inside the block, but the value of $result is null, I can see it through xdebug.
Why is this happening?

edit:
here's a screenshot
[image: screenshot]

here's what var_dump shows:

> string '{    "results" : [],    "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS" } '
>   (length=52)

This fixed it:

```
        $result = @json_decode($result, true);

    if(!empty($result['results'])) {
```

Comment: `if (null)` will always give you false. Is the value of $result `"null"` as in string, or the real null ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a

```
var_dump($result);
die;
```

Right after the curl response, and do that for one you know should be null and them examine what the result is? It might not be returning null ever..
Remember the value "" is not a NULL value, it is a "" value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the function `is_null()`?

```
if(!is_null($result)) { ... }
```

**[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this..May be its because of spaces.. also `echo strlen($result);` after your curl_exec will help you to check if the result is empty or not.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?         address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=true');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

if(trim($result)!='') {
 $result = @json_decode($result, true);
 $result = @$result['results'][0]['address_components'];
 foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value['types'][0] == 'administrative_area_level_2')
        return $value['long_name'];
 }
} else {
throw new Exception('unable to look up the county');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code an ran it with an address.
`$result` was not json but html because the url is invalid (404).
`json_decode` returned `null` because the string could not be decoded.

At least two suggested modifications:

1 - In the url remove the space between `...json?` and `address=...`
2 - Use `json_last_error` and/or check return value of `json_decode` to see if json was properly decoded.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php